# Why did this worked on someone and else not me?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define W 1031
#define B 256

struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct position *next;
};

struct wordFiles {
    char *fileName;
    struct position *cor;
    struct wordFiles *next;
};

struct wordTree {
    char *word;
    struct wordFiles *files;
    struct wordTree *left;
    struct wordTree *right;
};

struct wordTree *hashTable[W];

typedef struct wordFiles *files_Ptr;

typedef struct position *pos_ptr;

typedef struct wordTree *wordTreePtr;

long int power(int a, long b){
    long int value,i;
    value = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
        value *= a;
    return value;
}

int hashValue (char *word){
    long int i=0,s=0,n;
    n = strlen(word);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        s += power(B,n-i-1) * word[i];
    }
    return (s%W);
}

void readword(char *word , FILE *curr_file, int *x_axis, int *y_axis, int *newline, int *endfile){
    char c;
    c = (char) malloc(sizeof(char));
    if ((fscanf(curr_file, "%s", word))!=1 || fscanf(curr_file, "%c", &c)!=1){
        *endfile=1;
    }
    *x_axis += strlen(word);
    if (strlen(word)==1 && c=='\n'){
        *newline = 1;
        return;
    }
    if (c==' ') {
        *x_axis +=1;
    }
    else if (c=='\n') {
        *newline = 1;
    }
    return;
}

void coordinateslistInsert (pos_ptr *lp,int x, int y){
    pos_ptr prev,curr;
    prev = NULL;
    curr = *lp;
    while (curr != NULL){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    pos_ptr n = (pos_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct position));
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return;
    }
    n->next = NULL;
    n->x = x;
    n->y = y;
    if (prev==NULL) {
        *lp = n;
    }
    else {
        prev->next = n;
    }
    return;
}

void filelistInsert (files_Ptr *lp, char *filename, int x, int y, int k) {
    files_Ptr prev, curr;
    prev = NULL;
    curr = *lp;
    if ( curr!=NULL && k == 1 && strcmp(curr->fileName, filename) == 0 ){
        coordinateslistInsert(&(*lp)->cor, x, y);
        return;
    }
    while (curr != NULL){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    files_Ptr n = (files_Ptr)malloc(sizeof(struct wordFiles));
    if (n == NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return;
    }
    n->fileName = filename;
    n->next = NULL;
    coordinateslistInsert (&(*n).cor , x ,y);
    if (prev==NULL) {
        *lp = n;
    }
    else {
        prev->next = n;
    }
    return;
}

void treeBalancedInsert (wordTreePtr *curr_tree, char *word, char *filename, int x, int y) {
    int k=0;
    if (*curr_tree == NULL) {
        *curr_tree =(wordTreePtr) malloc(sizeof(struct wordTree));
        if (*curr_tree == NULL) {
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        (*curr_tree)->word=malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        (*curr_tree)->left = (*curr_tree)->right = NULL;
        strcpy((*curr_tree)->word,word);
        filelistInsert (&(*curr_tree)->files , filename,x,y,k);
    }
    else {
        if (strcmp((*curr_tree)->word,word) == 0){
            k=1;
            filelistInsert (&(*curr_tree)->files , filename,x,y,k);
            return;
        }
        else if (strcmp((*curr_tree)->word,word) < 0)
            treeBalancedInsert(&(((*curr_tree)->left)), word, filename, x, y);
        else
            treeBalancedInsert(&(((*curr_tree)->right)), word, filename,x ,y);
    }

}

void search (char *word, int h_value, struct wordTree *hashtable[]){
    wordTreePtr n = hashTable[h_value];
    while(n!=NULL && strcmp ( n->word , word ) !=0){
        if (strcmp ( n->word , word ) > 0 ){
            n = n->right;
        }
        else if(strcmp ( n->word , word ) < 0){
            n = n->left;
        }
    }
    if (n==NULL){
        printf("NOT FOUND");
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n",n->word);
    files_Ptr k = n->files;
    while (k!=NULL) {
        pos_ptr q = k->cor ;
        while (q!=NULL) {
            printf("%s(%d,%d)\n",k->fileName,q->y,q->x);
            q = q->next;
        }
        k = k->next;
    }
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j,i;
    for (i=0; i<W; i++){
        hashTable[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (j=1; j<argc; j++){
        FILE *curr_file=fopen(argv[j], "r+");
        int h_value = 0, x_axis = 1, y_axis=1, newline=0,endfile=0;
        if (curr_file == NULL) {
            perror("Error: ");
            return (-1);
        }
        char *word=NULL , *filename;
        filename = (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        filename = argv[j];
        while (endfile!=1){
            word = (char *) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
            readword(word, curr_file, &x_axis, &y_axis, &newline, &endfile);
            h_value = hashValue(word);
            treeBalancedInsert(&hashTable[h_value], word, filename, x_axis-(unsigned)strlen(word)-1, y_axis);
            if (newline==1){
                y_axis +=1;
                x_axis=1;
                newline=0;
            }
        }
        fclose(curr_file);
        free(word);
    }
    char *wordToSearch;
    wordToSearch = (char *) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",wordToSearch);
    search(wordToSearch,hashValue(wordToSearch),hashTable);
    return 0;
}
```

and it was written on a mac, and supposedly works. But when i compile and run on my machine it just wont.
What it does is it takes text files as arguments and sorts the words in binary trees which are placed in the hashtable depending the hashvalue of the word. And then you can type a word and it tells you the coordinates it appears and which files.

Anyway, debugging on eclipse step by step stucks at the (curr=curr->next) of the filelistInsert and code blocks shows 2 more problems, one at the treebalancedinsert function where it calls for the filelistinsert function and at the main when it calls for the treebalancedinsertfunction. 
I cant find what's wrong in the filelistinsert and im short on time. (i know it's an awful question, but im desperate)

Comment: Without even looking at the code yet, undefined behaviour. I guarantee it. I'm not sure what you want `char c;
    c = (char) malloc(sizeof(char));` to do. Unfortunately, the C compiler didn't complain about that, only the C++ one.

Comment: Maybe a buffer overflow. But this depends on the files given as arguments and what you input via `stdin`. What's your input?

Comment: files are .txt files with a text containing no commas, periods etc.

Comment: This is useless information. If any of them starts with 18 non-whitespace characters or more, followed by another character, you have a buffer overflow. If you input more than 18 non-whitespace characters via `stdin`, you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: It would help if you defined "won't work".  Does the code crash?  Does it hang?  Does it give you incorrect output?  If so, what are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: it just crashes, even before scaning the keyword

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
char c;
c = (char) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

to

```
char c;
```

Note: this is an error in your program but it is does not explain why your program is crashing.

Elsewhere:

```
    filename = (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    filename = argv[j];
```

It is a memory leak and also if you then suppose `filename` to be an array of `30` characters you might have troubles.

Comment: But surely `c` containing the cast to `char` of the result of `malloc` cannot be worse than `c` being uninitialized, and must not be the only problem in the program.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Did you read the function? It is initialized in `fscanf(curr_file, "%c", &c)` just after its declaration.

Comment: No, I didn't read the function. I am just saying that apart from the minor memory leak, whatever problem causes the program not to “worked” with the pattern `char c; c = (char) malloc(sizeof(char));` still causes it not to work with `char c;`.

Comment: yes actually i forgot to remove that from the code, thanks anyway

Comment: @PascalCuoq I agree with that and I added a note to my answer. I cannot find the courage to investigate furthermore.

Comment: why is the filename mallocing and setting to argv memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems.

The first thing that has alarm bells going off in my head are lines like

```
(*curr_tree)->word=malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

and

```
word = (char *) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

If you read any word that's longer than 19 characters from your input file, you're going to have a buffer overflow, which will cause heartburn at some point.  I'm reasonably sure that this is the source of your problem (when I run this program on its own source text, I start getting segfaults after reading "`(*curr_tree)->word=malloc(30*sizeof(char));`", most likely because we overflow a 20-character buffer and clobber something else.

The `readword` function should decide how much memory to allocate for a word based on the contents of the input file.  This means you're going to have to make the `readword` function a bit smarter, and have it allocate/reallocate a buffer as it's reading input, something like the following:

```
void readword(char **word , FILE *curr_file, int *x_axis, int *y_axis, int *newline, int *endfile){
    int c;
    size_t bufLen = 0;
    const size_t bufExtent=10;
    size_t idx = 0;

    *word = NULL;

    /**
     * Read input one character at a time until we see a space or EOF
     */
    while ( ( c = fgetc( curr_file ) ) != EOF && !isspace( c ))
    {
      /**
       * Are we at the end of our buffer?
       */
      if ( idx == bufLen )
      {
        /**
         * Extend the buffer
         */
        char *tmp = realloc( *word, bufLen + bufExtent );
        if ( tmp )
        {
          bufLen += bufExtent;
          *word = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
          fprintf( stderr, "readword: Could not allocate memory to extend word\n" );
          return;
        }
      }
      (*word)[idx++] = c;
    }
   /**
     * If we read a string, 0-terminate it
     */
    if ( *word )
    {
      (*word)[idx] = 0;
      *x_axis += strlen(*word);
    }
```

However, even with this I'm still getting runtime errors, so there are other time bombs hiding in this code.

Then there's this:

```
filename = (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
filename = argv[j];
```

This does not copy the contents of `argv[j]` to the memory you just allocated; instead, it assigns the pointer value of `argv[j]` to `filename`, overwriting the pointer to the memory you just allocated, leading to a memory leak.  And again, you're picking an arbitrary length for the filename.  Try something like the following:

```
filename = malloc( strlen( argv[j] ) + 1 );
strcpy( filename, argv[j] );
```

Style nit:

Hiding pointer types behind typedefs is *not* recommended, unless the type is meant to be opaque and never derferenced directly.  If I see the `*` in the object declaration, I immediately *know* how it's supposed to be used in an expression.  Using a `foo_ptr` typedef may make the code scan a little better, but it hinders undersatnding IMO.  I've been bitten by this enough over the years to where I avoid using typedefs in general.